# plsql: use collection to insert data from one table to another table

Tags: plsql

I encounter a problem that I want to use a collection to move data from one table to another table, and the code is below.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c IS SELECT first_name, last_name, salary FROM hr.employees; 
    TYPE l_data IS RECORD(fname VARCHAR2(25), lname VARCHAR2(25), salary NUMBER(9));
    TYPE t_nt IS TABLE OF l_data;
    v_lookup t_nt:=t_nt();
    v_increment number:=1;
    i NUMBER(2);
BEGIN
open c;
loop
fetch c BULK COLLECT INTO v_lookup;

FORALL i IN 1..v_lookup.COUNT
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES v_lookup(i);
EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
commit;
END LOOP;
close c;
 END;

CREATE TABLE t2 AS SELECT first_name, last_name, salary FROM hr.employees WHERE 1 = 2;

select * from t2;
```

After that when I select * from t2 it shows nothing.
So I don't know what happens.
And finally, how can I use buck_exception to handle the exceptions. Anyone can show me an example, please?

Comment: I'm not sure what that loop is for.

Comment: It looks like you created t2 after running the block that was supposed to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have `WHERE 1 = 2` in your WHERE clause in your `CREATE TABLE` statement.  This will always evaluate as false, so you'll never get data in `t2`.